# overriding template and controller in specific cases

Tags: symfony, overriding, bundle

I have two bundles A and B, in B I needed to override a template of A, so I used [bundle inheritence](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).
Everything works well so far, but now I need to override the template of the bundle A only in some specific cases. I tried this in the action of the bundle B (which overrides the action of the bundle A):

```
class ArticleController extends BaseArticleController
{
   public function detailsAction(Request $request, $article)
   {
        if('general' === $article->getType()) {
             // this doesn't return the template of the bundle A :(
             return parent::detailsAction($request, $article);
        }
        // else go on on rendering the other template...
   }
```

But this overrides anyway and it returns the template of the bundle B even if the type of my article is `'general'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the "bug", I wasn't desinging right the whole overriding thing: since I'm overriding the controller of A, it's totally useless to override the twig, so I renamed the twig of the bundle B. This way it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

just do something like this:

```
public function detailsAction(Request $request, $article)
{
    if('general' === $article->getType()) {
         // this doesn't return the template of the bundle A :(
         return parent::detailsAction($request, $article);
    }
    // else go on on rendering the other template...

    return $this->render('YourBundleA:YourControllerA:YourTemplateA.html.twig', array(...));
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, but it's rendering the template of B because it has the same name as in the bundle A. I've posted which I believe a good solution